# How to install geopandas in linux when fiona is not working?

Tags: python, linux, package, geopandas, fiona

I have tried to install geopandas in different ways and I always have some type of error.
First, I did  `conda install -c conda-forge geopandas`  but it said that I needed Fiona, then I try to install Fiona in the same way (`conda install -c conda-forge fiona` ). That never worked,because it said that there were inconsistencies with some packages. 
Then I tried  `conda install fiona` and  `conda install geopandas` and I got the same problem about the inconsistencies. 
Then I created a new conda environment without any package and installed individually the dependencies as suggested in the installation section of [geopandas manual](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/getting_started/install.html), pandas, numpy and shapely were correctly installed with  `conda install <package>` but again fiona did not install and gave the exact same problem.
Also, I followed the [Unix-like system installation for fiona](https://fiona.readthedocs.io/en/latest/README.html#installation) and apparently it worked, but Fiona was not in the list of packages in conda, though I tried to install geopandas and it did not work.

Finally, I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51807423/import-error-geopandas-fiona) and conda-forge does not install fiona with geopandas as it should then I got the error that I needed fiona to use geopandas.

Then, **how is geopandas and fiona correctly installed?**

Comment: you probably have conflicting dependencies or environments. make sure you're always pointing to the same version of conda with `which conda`. start from a fresh environment, and if you keep having this issue, try deleting & re-installing conda. Make sure conda is up to date with `conda update conda`, and then install both in one go with `conda install -c conda-forge fiona geopandas`. also, try [`mamba`](https://github.com/mamba-org/mamba) - it's conda but faster.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.